# Codacy yaml configuration to ignore duplication in test files

Tags: yaml, codacy

I'd like to exclude the duplication check from my test files, but leave everything else the same.

This is my `.codacy.yml` file:

```
duplication:
  enabled: true
  exclude_paths:
    - 'test/**'
    - '**.test.js'
```

But I still get all duplications reported in test files.

Anyone knows how to accomplish this?

**EDIT** Based on below suggestions I tried:

```
engines:
  duplication:
    enabled: true
    exclude_paths:
      - 'test/**'
      - '**.test.js'
```

And I tried without the quotes as well:

```
engines:
  duplication:
    enabled: true
    exclude_paths:
      - test/**
      - '**.test.js'
```

Still no dice :(

Comment: I just came across this question and it helped me. It worked for our Android project. The only difference was that I did `- '**/test/**'`.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be missing the `engines` property on your configuration file that is required for the duplication configuration to be applied.

You should change your configuration file to look like this:

```
engines:
  duplication:
    enabled: true
    exclude_paths:
      - 'test/**'
      - '**.test.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

your config file seems wrong.

Check the docs at:

- https://support.codacy.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002130625-Codacy-Configuration-File
- https://support.codacy.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005097654-Ignore-files-from-Codacy-analysis

should be something like:

```
engines:
  duplication:
    enabled: true
    exclude_paths:
      - 'test/**'
      - '**.test.js'
```

Comment: I tried that first though, but it also did not work and it kind of didn't make sense to have a global setting under engines? I'll try it again now.

Comment: Did not work. It still reports duplication in test files :(

Comment: It's weird. You should contact Codacy in app support so that they can give you a better explanation of the problem. Share your findings then please